# Encryption used in Multipeer Connectivity framework?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, chat, multipeer-connectivity

Hey I am using a multi peer Connectivity framework in ios for a chat application . Does this framework support any encryption .I want to know about the encryption used in this framework like AES OR RSA encryption systems? 
My findings or research:
1. https://datatheorem.github.io/documents/BH_MultipeerConnectivity.pdf
2. https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2014/08/20/multipeer-connectivity-follow-up/

Please post ur suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an **encryption** option in **MCSession.h** class

```
 // Encryption preference.
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, MCEncryptionPreference) {
MCEncryptionOptional = 0,                   // session preferred encryption but will accept unencrypted connections
MCEncryptionRequired = 1,                   // session requires encryption
MCEncryptionNone = 2,                       // session should not be encrypted
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE (10_10, 7_0);
```

call this method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithPeer:(MCPeerID *)myPeerID
        securityIdentity:(nullable NSArray *)identity
    encryptionPreference:(MCEncryptionPreference)encryptionPreference NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . What kind of encryption is this ?  RSA or AES ?

Comment: Please suggest what encryption method they follow?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, `MCSession` uses `DTLS` to encrypt it's data. `DTLS` is based on `TLS` (which is the replacement of `SSL`), and offers the same level of security.

So just uses

```
MCSession *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID
                                securityIdentity:nil
                            encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionRequired];
```

to make your communications secure.